# Redis hGet does not giving any response when the redis connection failed

Tags: node.js, npm, redis

With redis 4.0.1 version of npm package

After redis connection failed. If we try hGet we used to get an error.

But with the latest redis 4.6.5 version of the npm package. I'm not getting any such error. The request is being loaded infinitely.

Can someone help me how to handle this?

Comment: "we get an error" – what error? What code are you running?

Comment: To get help you'll need to post a reproducible code sample and provide details on which Redis you're connecting to - server version, who hosts it if anyone, whether you're using a password, username and password to connect etc.